# Use of implicits in Play 2.5 ActionRefiner

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am trying to create my own ActionRefiner to accommodate authentication, but for some reason the compiler won't let me use implicit variables in the `refine[A]` function... I have the following code:

```
trait Auth {
  object AuthenticatedAction extends ActionBuilder[AuthRequest] with ActionRefiner[Request, AuthRequest] {

    def refine[A](request: Request[A])(implicit userCollection: UserCollection, ex: ExecutionContext): Future[Either[Result, AuthRequest[A]]] = {
      request.session.get("username") match {
        case Some(username) => userCollection.findByEmail(username).map { userOpt =>
          userOpt.map(new AuthRequest(_, request)).toRight(Results.Redirect(routes.LoginController.login()))
        }
        case None => Future.successful(Left(Results.Redirect(routes.LoginController.login())))
      }
    }
  }
}

class AuthRequest[A](val user: User, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)
```

The Scala compiler tells me that the method `refine[A](request: R[A]): Future[Either[Result, P[A]]]` is not defined. When I remove the implicit variables it registers, but that leaves me with no `UserCollection`...

So, How do I correctly use the ActionRefiner?

Comment: this is due to the fact that when you add implicit arguments, the function no longer matches the abstract definition of `refine` from `ActionRefiner`. that's why you get a "not defined" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/aUIjB2R6BE4) I found a way to make it work. Instead of using an implicit, I can define the `UserCollection` in the trait and pass it from my controller, like so:

```
trait Auth {
  def userCollection: UserCollection

  object AuthenticatedAction extends ActionBuilder[AuthRequest] with ActionRefiner[Request, AuthRequest] {
    def refine[A](request: Request[A]): Future[Either[Result, AuthRequest[A]]] = {
      ...
    }
  }
}

class HomeController @Inject()(val userCollection: UserCollection)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends Controller with Auth {
  def index = AuthenticatedAction { implicit request =>
    Ok(s"Hello ${request.user.name}")
  }
}
```

I just had gotten so used to using implicits that I completely forgot about this.